# Learning XCODE, different aspects to it

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I am looking forward to learning XCODE, what is an appropriate approach to mastering ios programming. I want to know precisely, in order, what I should learn to know XCODE. Since there are different aspects to XCODE, I am confused on where to start. Such as COCOA, objective-C, etc. Can anyone provide me with a solid plan that will give me a solid programming skills with XCODE? Thank You

Comment: We're here to help with programming problems, not be teachers, or recommend ways to learn something.

Comment: Try searching youtube, for `iOS tutorial`. I like the channel http://www.youtube.com/user/AppleProgramming

Answer (score 2):

Start with a good book that teaches you Objective-C with Xcode 5. 
Stephen Kochan has a good one.

That will get you going. 
But check a few to see what makes sense to you. 
Just make sure it has Xcode 5 so you don't get lost.

After you get through a bit with Objective-C you should fill in what you need of C.

C is not hard but it is truly agnostic from frameworks that really do interesting things so it makes learning C first rather challenging. 
(Like learning math without any real idea why or what to use it for)

In the end though, expect a long road of perpetual learning. You will feel overwhelmed at times. That's normal. 
Nobody knows all if it and the masters have years of experience and knowledge.